# What to do if I run out of flags

Tags: discussion, support, flags, review

I've seen a couple of questions about what to do if I run out of moderator flags (not normally a problem since I have 39). However, when using review-beta I've been running across a lot of low-quality questions that probably need to be closed. So I ran out of flags (I've reviewed 362 posts today).

I'm not quite sure what to do... I don't really want to hit "Not Sure" when I see a bad question (because I *am* sure that it should go).

Hopefully this won't be a problem for me much longer (I'm *so close* to 3000 rep) but I would welcome some suggestions/feature requests.

The problem is that I have to review low-quality questions and answers at the same time, so I keep getting shown bad questions that I have to do *something* to in order to see other posts.

...haha if you add up my (as-of-this-moment) meta & SO rep I have 2999 reputation.

Comment: You stop flagging for the day.

Comment: You take your shotgun and hunt down the people responsible...

Comment: Hate to tell you, but you get limited close votes too

Comment: @BenBrocka LIFE HAS NO MEANING

Comment: Personally, I still use flag for closing even after I got close privilege. I use them specifically for old, *confirmed* bad question. It allows the question to be closed quicker, rather than spending extra time in the >50k close vote queue.

Comment: @Dustin ah so we meet here too? (got +1 from me btw)

Comment: @H2CO3 yeppp I have a pretty good number of posts queued up from here. Some of this stuff is a gold mine.

Comment: Go do something not related to the site.  Seriously.  While rate limiting is to prevent acceleration of *any* behavior to the point where it can't be controlled, it also has the secondary effect of saying "hey, you've had enough for the day, go enjoy the sun."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of three things:

1. Switch to a different queue.
2. Hit "Not Sure" - this won't dequeue the item for other users, so you're doing no harm.
3. Go answer questions until you hit 3K reputation, so you don't have to burn flags on questions that need to be closed.

(There's a possible fourth option involving going outside and/or maybe doing work, but let's not get *too* silly)

Comment: Doing work? Pshh. Using SO makes me so good at work that I can spend ALL THE TIME on it and still get everything done.

Comment: You're saying this to the guy who gets work done *by using SO*.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Don't rub it in our faces.